# Video modal not getting rendered again after discarding the photo taken using capacitor plugin and react

Tags: reactjs, capacitor

I am using the capacitor camera plugin to use camera API in my React PWA. Everything works fine and the photo taken gets saved successfully. It is only when I discard the photo taken and tries to take the photo again, the camera video displays a black screen.

This happens after I click the bottom right cross button on the screen to either accept or discard the photo. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlUsy.png)

Here is my code:

```
takePicture = () => {
    Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 50,
      source: CameraSource.Camera,
      correctOrientation: true,
      width: 200,
      resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
    })
      .then((image, error) => {
        console.log('Image: ', error);
        this.setState({ imgSrc: image.dataUrl });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```